# Why Supervisor's HTTP server won't work?

Tags: supervisord

I've installed Supervisor in a ubuntu based vps, and it takes effect on starting other processes. But I can't visit it's monitor page from ip:9001 in browser.
I config inet_http_server in /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf:

```
[inet_http_server]
port = 127.0.0.1:9001
username = user
password = 123
```

Also tried port ":9001" or "0.0.0.0:9001", and execute `sudo service supervisor restart; sudo supervisorctl reload` after each configuration. But I can't visit ip:port from local browser, and when I check `netstat -anp | grep 9001` in the server, no process is found.

Answer (score 6):

Did you put a `*` before `9001`?

This is what works for me:

```
[inet_http_server]         ; inet (TCP) server disabled by default
port=*:9001        ; (ip_address:port specifier, *:port for all iface)
; username=user              ; (default is no username (open server))
; password=123               ; (default is no password (open server))
```

make sure you aren't using HTTPS to connect from the browser!

Answer (score 2):

Just make sure your config has taken effect by issuing the following command:

```
supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
```

(in the case that the config section `[inet_http_server]` is included in your `/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf` file)

Answer (score 2):

simply change

```
port = 127.0.0.1:9001
```

to

```
port = 9001
```

not sure why most people will add IP addr for the port variable, but this will work

Comment: To be fair, `echo_supervisord_conf` outputs the sample configuration text. And part of it is: _port=127.0.0.1:9001 (ip_address:port specifier, *:port for all iface)_

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to define the required permission on the firewall

```
sudo ufw allow 9001/tcp
```

restart Supervisor

```
sudo systemctl restart supervisor
```